# Jquery: How to dynamically add/remove html data at the end of div container

Tags: jquery

i tried to dynamically add html data at the end of div container but i guess there is some mistake in code and not getting desired output. here is my code. just tell me what is wrong there.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var $htmlelement=$('<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>');

var isDate=1;
alert('pp');
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(isDate==1)
  {
   alert('pp');
   $('#datetimepicker1').append($htmlelement);
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to conditionally add the content or as your title suggestion add and later remove the content?...

Comment: If this is the actual script then check the console for the error.

Comment: yes when isDate is 1 then html will be added at the end of datetimepicker1 div and when isDate is 0 then html will be removed from datetimepicker1 div.

Comment: there's newlines in your `var $htmlelement` statement, when fixed it alerts "pp" and appends the `span` to the `div`

Comment: i used alert for debug purpose.

Comment: Just open the console of your browser and check the error

Comment: The object `<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>` is created, add a text in the span and this show, example: `<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>your text here</span>` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's newlines in your `var $htmlelement` statement, when fixed it alerts, and appends the `span` to the `div`:

```js
var $htmlelement=$('<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>your span here</span>');

var isDate=1;
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(isDate==1)
  {
   alert('appending');
   $('#datetimepicker1').append($htmlelement);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you did not show how to remove what is stored in $htmlelement if it is already there.